# R programming language breaks and must be reinstalled

Tags: install, r

Yesterday, I tried to open the R programming environment by typing "R" at the command line.  I was met with the following error message:

```
Fatal error: unable to open the base package
```

I didn't know what to do about that, so I re-installed R.  That fixed the problem, so I went on with my day.

Today, I am met with the same error when I type "R" at the command line.  I am bamboozled!

Comment: What happened since yesterday and today? Did you install it correctly?

Comment: Just used the Mac installer from http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/

Comment: Is it your computer? Is it possible something is occurring overnight that resets user-installed software?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Currently on OS X Sierra, haven't had this problem in a while.  Not sure which version I was on in September.